# redisTemplate.opsForZSet().reverseRange return type not as expected

Tags: spring, spring-data-redis

I have a zset in redis, store all numbers, like 11,22,33...etc, when I use

```
Set<Long> tops = redisTemplate.opsForZSet().reverseRange(key, 0, -1);
```

I expect the return type to be Long, but it returns Integer.

why??

any tips how to solve this??

Comment: What's your redistTemplate definition?

Comment: @Autowired
private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the [RedisTemplate#opsForZSet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html#opsForZSet--) method signature:

```
 public ZSetOperations<K,V> opsForZSet()
```

It return the same value type (`V`) as defined in `RedisTemplate`.

Your method return Integer because your `RedisTemplate` define Integer as value.

If another RedisTemplate with Integer value is needed, you should consider define another RedisTemplate with Long value

Comment: how to define that ? like this: RedisTemplate<String,Long> ?

Comment: Yes. It should be Long